# Normalize multivalue column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataset like this:

```
data = {'Host': ['A','A','A', 'A'], 'Seq': ['0, 1, 2, 99',' 4, 5, 6', '999, 8', '100']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to normalize all values.

First i go to this shape:

```
host Seq
 A    0
 A    1
 A    2
 A    99
 A    4
 A    5
 A    6
 A    999
 A    8
 A    100
```

By this code:

```
df.join(df.pop('Seq')
                .str.split(',',expand=True)
                .stack()
                .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                .rename('Seq')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

After just normalize by StandartScaler:

```
df['Seq'] = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(df.Seq.values).reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
```

And now i dont know how return to start view.
Waiting for ideas and comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you didn't destroy the index information from the original

```
d_ = df.assign(Seq=df.Seq.str.split(',\s*')).explode('Seq')

d_

  Host  Seq
0    A    0
0    A    1
0    A    2
0    A   99
1    A    4
1    A    5
1    A    6
2    A  999
2    A    8
3    A  100
```

Then you can group by the index and `'Host'` column

```
d_.groupby([d_.index, 'Host']).Seq.apply(', '.join).reset_index('Host')

  Host          Seq
0    A  0, 1, 2, 99
1    A      4, 5, 6
2    A       999, 8
3    A          100
```